# Is there any specified way to catch Solana pay transactions?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

How can I get Solana pay transactions from Solana mainnet cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for the `reference`, which is the publickey of a keypair generated and added to a Solana Pay transaction

```
import {findReference} from "@solana/pay"

// Check if there is any transaction for the reference
const signatureInfo = await findReference(connection, reference, {
     finality: "confirmed",
})
```

code snippet from here: https://github.com/pointer-gg/solana-pay-tutorial/blob/4-transaction-requests-v2/pages/checkout.tsx#L98

recommend this pointer.gg tutorial:
https://www.pointer.gg/tutorials/solana-pay-irl-payments/944eba7e-82c6-4527-b55c-5411cdf63b23